# Google Maps markers from XML

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps-markers

I tried to use Google Tutorial (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps)
I did XML output rightly, so we have a file, and an initialized map, but for some reasons markers do not appear, and we have an errors:
 
ReferenceError: marker is not defined
 and
 
ReferenceError: doNothing is not defined.
I have read some similar questions around, but unfortunately have not enough skills in JS to understand what actually I am missing.
Any help will be appreciated.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<markers>
<marker year="2019" lng="137.553619" lat="36.106525" name="Norikura" id="1"/>
<marker year="2019" lng="139.767151" lat="33.140198" name="Hachijou-jima" id="2"/>
<marker year="2019" lng="138.896469" lat="35.678909" name="Ubako" id="3"/>
<marker year="2020" lng="140.416473" lat="38.170666" name="Zao" id="4"/>
<marker year="2020" lng="138.370071" lat="35.999195" name="Io" id="5"/>
<marker year="2020" lng="139.167664" lat="35.781200" name="Hinode" id="6"/>
</markers>
```

HTML

```
<div id="map">
   <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAVpvd7SOVCDWe3XiCps1r6428suI7BMq0&callback=initMap">
   </script>
</div>
<script src="markersMap.js"></script>
```

markersMap.js

```
function initMap() {
  // The location of Fuji
  var fuji = {lat: 35.358056, lng: 138.731111};
  // The map, centered at Fuji
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 9, center: fuji});
 loadMarkers();
 }


function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
 var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
     new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
     new XMLHttpRequestfunction initMap() {


 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
     callback(request, request.status);
   }
 };

 request.open('GET', url, true);
 request.send(null);
}

downloadUrl('test1.xml', function(data) {
  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
    var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
    var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
    var year = markerElem.getAttribute('year');
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

    var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
    var strong = document.createElement('strong');
    strong.textContent = name
    infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
    infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

    var text = document.createElement('text');
    text.textContent = year
    infowincontent.appendChild(text);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point
   });
});
});

marker.addListener('click', function() {
  infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for doNothing
Seems like you're missing (check the tutorial)

```
function doNothing() {}
```

As for marker
In your code marker is defined inside downloadUrl function, while used outside
In tutorial it is used inside

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    label: icon.label
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```